What is the difference between わけにもいかない and わけにはいかない?
Is one of the versions more emphasized?
E.g. ２人が手を振っているのに無視をするわけにもいかないので、わたしも軽く手を振り返す。

わけにもいかない sounds milder and reserved (i.e., "it's not quite right to ignore them").

Doesn't it also mean "even"?

No, it doesn't. But it might mean "(not) either" if the context is "Aするわけにはいかないし、Bするわけにもいかない".
